# Adding c.py to simple project results in "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named c"

Tags: python-3.x, module, importerror

Not exactly a newbie but not an expert either, obviously. Could not find *this* problem elsewhere.

This is a simple layout created with Atom, and it used to work just fine from the terminal, but no more, since the module `c.py` has just been added. This layout *does* work as a PyCharm project.

Is this layout inherently flawed, or should it work in theory, assuming the simplest possible "hello world" functionality?

Thank you in advance.

```
 --blah
    |__blah
         |__a.py
         |__b.py
         |__c.py
```

```
#a.py
import b
import c

#do stuff
```

```
(venv)me blah $ python3
>>>import blah.a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c'
```

Comment: i use `vscode` and this would normally work as you expect in the example.  is it because you are in the (venv) ?

Comment: Not because of venv.  Assuming that vscode does the same thing PyCharm does, that is, map to the module behind the scenes, as per the post linked in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm, `blah.blah` is "marked as sources root".  Searching that led me to this post:  [What does "Mark directory as sources root" really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360738/what-does-mark-directory-as-sources-root-really-do)

Realizing that PyCharm did some things behind the scenes that I took for granted, I tried the following in the Atom version of the project:

```
import blah.c
```

which solved the problem.

Thus I surmise that the strict answer to the original question is, "no".